# Extra files in the project (NPGSQL)

Tags: c#, nuget, npgsql, .net-framework-version

The question is stupid enough, but it didn’t work with NuGet before. After installing the NuGet package through the console, to connect to PostgreSQL, files appeared that NetFramework should contain. Without copying these files, the project does not start. What to do to get rid of them and not copy them to the directory with the program. In my understanding, these files should be taken from the framework.

See screenshots:
[All need files in project C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1HBi.png)

Comment: What is the TargetFramework for your project?

Comment: @TommyN - NetFramework 4.6.1 These are its built-in libraries. It is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have .Net Standard 2.0 libraries/dependencies in your project. 
.NET 4.6.1 might add additional runtime dependencies in your output folder:

> .NET 4.6.1, 4.6.2, .NET 4.7 and 4.7.1 all have partial .NET Standard
>   2.0 support in the natively shipped runtimes, but they still are .NET Standard 2.0 compliant by adding additional runtime dependencies into
>   your output folder to provide the missing functionality. NuGet along
>   with the runtime targeting handles automatically adding those
>   dependencies to your projects to provide the needed runtime support
>   for those extra features. A lot of those assemblies override behavior
>   from the base framework and .NET uses runtime redirects to route api
>   calls to the appropriate assemblies rather than than mscorlib.dll or
>   other system assemblies.
>
> .NET 4.7.2 is the first version of the full .NET Framework that is
>   fully .NET Standard 2.0 compliant without any additional dependencies.

See: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/Using-NET-Standard-with-Full-Framework-NET

In other words, targeting .NET 4.7.2 should get rid of the additional files.